Reed-Solomon error count if errors cannot be corrected
I have to implement a RS algorithm for encoding/decoding. The main question I have is how I can count the number of errors in a message to be decoded? I know that it can be done for fewer than or t errors from the error-locator polynomial. But what about the case where we have more than t errors? Is it possible to count those errors (as long as we stay within 2t)?
If it is no possible to count them, I have a second related question:
I have read some threads indicating that some ways to check for inconsistencies in the decoding process are:

Getting less than degree(error_locator_polynomial) roots when calculating the positions of errors via Chien search.
One of the found error positions have a 0 error value according to Forney's equation.
The decoded message is not valid.

These checks will enable me to distinguish between the case where the errors are correctable and when they aren't. But that raises a new question: Are those methods exhaustive? What I mean is if I can be certain that, by using those three checks, I will detect all cases where there are between t+1 and 2t errors?
*Consider that there isn't any erasure.

The last of the three checks that you list is exhaustive but expensive to implement while the other two are cheaper to implement  but not guaranteed to be exhaustive. All this is mentioned in the "threads" that you claim to have read. None of these checks will tell you how many errors have actually occurred; only that an uncorrectable number of errors has occurred, and so any output that the decoder might provide, or might have already provided, is not a valid codeword.

So, leaving aside those safety-check methods, there is no way to count the number of errors when there are more than t, is it?

Yes, there is no way to count the errors that have occurred when the number of errors exceeds $t$. In fact, matters are even worse: all that can be said after any of the checks stated in this answer is that the received word is not at distance $t$ or less from any valid codeword, and that the "decoder output" (if the decoder has gone through the Chien search and Forney algorithm calculations and produced a "codeword" as its output after applying said corrections) is not a valid codeword.

Indeed, there is no guaranteed way to count the  number of errors that actually have occurred even after the decoder has successfully produced a valid codeword as its output. With high probability, the number of errors that actually occurred is  the number of errors that the decoder has corrected, but there is some chance that the number of errors that actually occurred is much larger, and the decoder has produced a (valid) codeword other than the codeword actually transmitted (because that other codeword is at distance $t$ or less from the received word).

… and that's why even with extensive error correction, practical systems almost always contain a checksum for the transported data somehow; while it's still possible that you had a "mis-corrected" amount of errors and thus ended up in the wrong codeword, that happening and then the checksum still being incorrectly correct is very very unlikely. (also, there's list decoders that can use such a checksum as a pseudo-genie for correct decoding, but that's a whole new can of interesting worms. Or, considering the involvement of a something like a genie, maybe whole new magic lamp of worms?)

You're then in the case that you're closer to a different code word than the original one; in other words, the maximum error count that a maximum likelihood decoder could ever yield would be half the detectable errors (rounded up).

Lots of incorrect statements here caused by using $t$ as the symbol for the minimum distance less $1$ instead of the error-correction capability as has become the de facto standard in coding theory circles and certainly as used and understood by the OP.

@DilipSarwate but the distance of an MDS code like RS is $n-k+1$, and that minus 1 is exactly the error detection capability of an RS code. So I must admit I don't understand your point. They are the same.

The point is that in the OP's question, $t$ is the error-correcting capability, meaning that if $t$ or fewer errors have occurred, then the decoder is guaranteed to correct them and produce the transmitted codeword as its output. You have chosen to use $t$ as the error-detection capability, with no warning to the reader that you are using a different meaning for $t$ that what the OP has used. At least have the common courtesy to tell people up front that your $t$ is not the same as the OP's $t$.

@DilipSarwate excuse me for contradicting you there regarding "with no warning". My answer literally starts with $t=n-k$. There's no ambiguity there.

I disagree: Your answer starts with a quotation of the OP's query: "But what about the case where we have more that $t$ errors?" where the OP's $t$ very definitely denotes the error-correcting capability, and in the very beginning of your answer, you change the meaning of $t$ to make it the error-detection capability without any warning to the reader that what you mean by $t$ is quite different from the meaning of $t$ in the query just quoted, and use this different meaning of $t$ in the rest of your answer.

ah I'm beginning to see your point. But, fine, then we just introduce a different symbol for $t$ in my answer, and we end with essentially the same info: if we travel more than half the distance, the error we can count are again less than half the distance, just the distance to a different symbol.

@DilipSarwate removed the conflicting symbols; is that agreeable?
